# Visibility of Confluence user sessions?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I can easily view user sessions in Jira by accessing System > Security > User Sessions (see documentation [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/viewing-user-sessions-720412310.html)).

However, I can not find a similiar option in Confluence. Is it possible to access the user sessions in Confluence?

In the end, I would like to access it programmatically but I am afraid that if there is not even a way to get there via the UI, I am out of luck doing so via the Confluence API.

The question was asked [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Confluence-Visibility-of-user-sessions/qaq-p/349771) already, but there was no satisfying answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Confluence User List macro (confluence server):
https://confluence.atlassian.com/confeap/user-list-macro-480346630.html?_ga=2.138789171.1460206440.1517834060-1884022569.1490585845

Don't forget to enable the User Log In Listener module as described in the instructions of the link I shared above to be able to see online/offline users.

As for an API way, I don't think there is a way to do this at the moment. You can try and find a way to build your own plugin that extends the listener module used by the above macro if that is even possible.

Comment: Thank you. It is unfortunate that there is currently no way to access user sessions via the API.